# Homework Service

Tags: discussion, homework

I am a student of Computer Science, however for the most part I'm self teaching myself CS(Due to being in a not very good school, which is not internationally competitive or standard. Not to say I don't learn anything in school, but we tend not to cover topics as much as I like.)

So in the books I read, I often encounter exercises which may be difficult, and I attempt to solve. As I have no teacher but myself(I haven't even started a course on Data Structures and/or algorithms yet) I am not able to verify my solutions.

Now these questions will normally be homework questions though in my case they're not(as I'm not doing it for any grade, nor do I get assessed on them except by myself).

While homework questions are officially allowed, high-rep users seem to dislike and downvote them.{I have also personally experienced this when asking homework like questions(I once more stress that I have not yet begun lectures on the topics I discuss here, so they weren't homework questions)}.

But with no teacher, I have no one to help me verify solution of the problem/solve them/point me in the right direction.

In some cases, I may want solutions and not just hints.

I'm asking if it is "okay" to lift textbook questions and ask them here. What are essentially homework questions, and where I in a different university or further along in my current one may be my homework questions.

Can I use this site as a "homework" service?

Comment: Not really, no. It does not matter if you ask a real homework, self homework or anything that sounds like it. We are not a homework service.

Comment: In the question you linked, the reason for not supporting homework questions was: "The purpose of homework exercises are (1) to give you practice, and (2) to help you self-diagnose gaps in your understanding. Therefore, asking us to solve your homework question is almost never a good idea -- it doesn't serve either of those purposes, and is likely to waste your time and ours." I'm doing exercise problems from a  book. I often get stuck on the more difficult ones. I have ***NO*** teacher to ask. If a WIkipedia/Google search won't help me, then I have no recourse.

Comment: Please keep in mind the level and the overall form of the question. If you rewrite verbatim copy of the excersise and add only "I do not know what to do" it is a poor question, also not helpful even to you. On the other hand the conceptual question is ok, so generally without an example it is hard to compare virtual yet to be writen ones with these that resulted in the discussion I have linked. But in general picking excersises from book and asking them one by one is not the best idea. Also this is not grading site - yes/no or 4+ answers are also bad here.

Comment: drop by [chat] & ppl are usually willing to give hints esp if you are responsive etc... self motivated/ ambitious/ hardworking/ communicative students are the best

Comment: "I have no one to help me verify solution of the problem" -- usually, there are ways to verify your solution that are interesting to pick up in their own right. Self-check your proofs, implement and test your algorithms, ...

Comment: The short answer is: no, you can't. Kudos for teaching yourself CS, that's a tough thing to do. It's a pity you are in this alone, at least in the meat space. But that doesn't change the nature of this site. Other platforms may exist that are a better fit (I don't know any myself). Our [chat] is certainly a possibility.